# Probabilities and Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

I am taking a course in probability and statistic and I have to solve this problem and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. The problem is:

An european football club is composed of: 3 goalkeepers, 5 strickers, 6 midfielders and 7 defenders. The coach of the team announces publicly that in the next match he will line up a formation with: 2 strickers, 4 midfielders, 4 defeanders and one goalkeeper. A supporter bet on a certain format, according to the coach's announcement. Which is the probability that the suporter wins the bet?

In the process of solving the problem I've tryed to apply the hypergeometric distribution and the result was 0.044653. It seems a little to small and I thought to ask here to be sure that is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of possible teams = $\binom31\binom52\binom64\binom74 = 15750$

Thus the *Pr* of correctly guessing a randomly formed team = $\frac1{15750}, \approx 0.00006349$,

even lower than what you computed !

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you give me an explanation why the number of favorite cases is 1?

Comment: @RaduHrihoreanu: Because only **one** of the $15750$ possible teams with the announced format will play on that day.